# set() Permission denied by Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have cannot set value to my Firebase database using set(). In logs it returns me set at Permission denied. See bellow set data code:

```
obj.db.fb.ref('forms/' + newKey).set({
  'author': 'test author',
  'title': 'test title',
  'categoryId': '1245',
  'userId': 1,
  'date': Date.now()
  //'data' : data.data.json
}, function(error) {
     console.log(error)
});
```

The database security rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
 ".read": "auth.uid != true",
  "userData":{
     "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"      
     }
   }
}
```

}

[However, I keep getting the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpMQd.png)

I have set security rules  only auth user can read and write data. They can working properly. see bellow security rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": "auth.uid != true",
   ".write": "auth.uid != true"      
 }
```

}

But I have set permission in the my application is data can read and set data auth user but update and delete data only auth user and user are created own data. Is it possible ? and What could go wrong?

Comment: Your rules give users permission to write to `/userData/$uid` if the `$uid` matches the current user's UID. Your code writes to `/forms/$newKey`. That is a different location, and since your rules don't give anyone write permission to that location, the write gets rejected.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I have also applied my database security rules are `{
 "rules": {  ".read": "auth.uid != true",  ".write": "auth.uid != true && newData.child('userId') == auth.uid"  } }`. But it returns me set at Permission denied. Please help for assign correct security rules.

Comment: You're missing `.val() at the end of `newData.child('userId`)` there.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I have also added `{  "rules": {  ".read": "auth.uid != true",  ".write": "auth.uid != true && newData.child('userId').val() == auth.uid"  } }` . But they can return permission denied.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really hard to figure out what's going on and comments are not an efficient way to debug. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include (only): 1) the rules you expect to work, 2) the code that doesn't work with these rules? Make sure that the code logs any values that your rules depend on (such as the UID of the signed in user). Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)